# Search at least one comma separated value from my sql table row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a query that will fetch result of at least one comma separated value match from table row.

Like my custom table has following values. 
[image]

```
SR value are inserted 3 times so i want whenever i execute `SELECT QUERY` that will search `SR` value is inserted or not, if `SR` values inserted then do nothing else insert new row.
```

i have used following query but it could not provided output that i want.

```
$get_old_model = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT model_name FROM `wp_make_details` WHERE `post_id` = ".$post_id."
            AND model_name LIKE '%".$modle_list."%'");
```

Anyone know more about it help me plz.

Comment: Did you use FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: Yes i used that function but it does not given me output that i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: normalisation ?

Answer (score 0):

quoting from [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) docs:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by , characters. If the first
>   argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET,
>   the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns
>   0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns
>   NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly
>   if the first argument contains a comma (,) character.
>
> ```
>  mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
>          -> 2
> ```

You may try following query for your case:

```
Select model_name from `wp_make_details` where  `post_id` = ".$post_id."
        AND model_name LIKE FIND_IN_SET('SR',model_name) != 0;
```

This query will return row if SR is already inserted into your table.

Comment: is it possible multiple value in find in set (), suppose my array return value 'SR', 'temp' and i pass this value in FIND_IN_SET () it given me blank result.